# why the variables become null?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

in flutter web, when i use the WebVideoWidget, like this. but always get " video is null in toPlay".

```
    Center(
      child: _video = WebVideoWidget(
                    //...
      ),
    )

    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        _video.src = _urlClip;
      });
   }
```

the WebVideoWidget src file

```
class WebVideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final _WebVideoWidgetState _state = _WebVideoWidgetState();

  @override
  _WebVideoWidgetState createState() => _state;
    
      set src(String value) {
        //this.src = value;
        _state.toPlay(src);
      }
    
    }
    
    class _WebVideoWidgetState extends State<WebVideoWidget> {
      VideoElement _video;
      Widget _videoWidget;
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _video = VideoElement();
        ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('webVideoElement', (int viewId) {
            //....
         return _video;
        }); 
        _videoWidget = HtmlElementView(key: UniqueKey(), viewType: 'webVideoElement');
      } 
      
      void toPlay(String url){
        if( _video==null )
          print('--------video is null in toPlay -------');
        else
          print('--------video is not null in toPlay-------');  
      }
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: widget.width.toDouble(),
              height: widget.height.toDouble(),
              child: _videoWidget,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Why all the property variables become null in toPlay function? I really can't figure out this strange problem. the html problem?

Comment: could you show your url?

Comment: @SaifulIslam, i get url from backend. like this:
http://localhost:3000/video_clips/get_video?id=5f33e24d149553a63c2e94cc

Comment: maybe i should construct a controller and pass it to the child widget to solve it?

Comment: include your full error log with your question that help more to understand.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is to construct a controller.
code sample here, hope can help.

```
    class WebVideoController {
      _WebVideoWidgetState _videoState;
    
      void setParent(_WebVideoWidgetState videoState) {
        this._videoState = videoState;
      }
    
      void play(url){
        this._videoState.toPlay(url);
      }
    }

  @override
  _WebVideoWidgetState createState() => _WebVideoWidgetState(controller);

  _WebVideoWidgetState(this.controller){
    this.controller.setParent(this);
  }
```